# How to find limit of $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1}(1 + \frac{k}{n})sin\frac{k\pi}{n^2}$

Tags: summation

How to find limit of $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1}(1 + \frac{k}{n})sin\frac{k\pi}{n^2}$

What i should to do then see sums like this?

Comment: have you asked Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Does WA provide guidance on methodologies to attack similar problems?  The OP is not simply seeking a value to the limit.   The OP is requesting possible ways forward.  Would you please refrain from reliance on computer algorithms to replace actual thought.  ;-)

Comment: @eugenekorotlov [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647807/evaluation-of-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sum-k-1n-sin-left-fracnn2k2/1647848#1647848) is a related problem.  -Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Taylor Lagrange inequality we have

$$\left\vert\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n^2}\right)-\frac{k\pi}{n^2}\right\vert\le \frac{M}{n^3}$$
so with this inequality we prove that the desired limit is equal to

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac kn\right)\frac{k\pi}n=\int_0^1(1+x)\pi xdx$$
using the Riemann sum.

Comment: (+1) This is solid.  [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647807/evaluation-of-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sum-k-1n-sin-left-fracnn2k2/1647848#1647848) is a related problem.